# How node.js handles multiple requests?

Tags: node.js

I have a node.js code which basically listen on a UDP socket for different requests coming from web pages, and calls a function to query DynamoDB and sends back the results to the appropriate calling web page (according the remote IP and Port to identify each request).

The code looks like this:

```
function qryDynamoDB(qry_condition, remoteIP, remotePort) {

    var qryParams = {
        TableName: "customer1",
        KeyConditionExpression: "qry_condition",
    };

    docClient.query(qryParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } 
        else {
            var qry = JSON.stringify(data);
            server.send(qry, 0, qry.length, remotePort, remoteIP, function (err, bytes) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

// UDP Server starts

server.on('listening', function () {

    var address = server.address();
    console.log('UDP Server listening on ' + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.on('message', function (message, remote) {

    // do a query
    qryDynamoDB('qry_condition', remote.address, remote.port);
});
```

My question is this code is safe in terms of multiple (almost) simultaneous requests. For example, I'm wondering if `Request#1` arrives and the code executes the query, and then `Request#2` also arrives and the code sends the ***2nd*** query. But if for some reason the last query finishes first (for example ***qry 1*** is more complex than ***qry 2***), would this result be sent back to the right remote IP and Port (coming from the web page that sent `Request#2`) and not the first one?

I don't know about node.js internals and how it handle this so I'm afraid of this situation happening and then mixing the results up.

I would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: I understand your concern. The answer for 1st question is YES - qry2 might be faster than qry1. And the way to handle it is put it into a queue and read one by one.